# Update JSON data type column in MySql table

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I have started using `MySQL 8` and trying to update `JSON data type` in a `mysql table`

My `table t1` looks as below:

```
# id    group   names   
1100000 group1  [{"name": "name1", "type": "user"}, {"name": "name2", "type": "user"}, {"name": "techDept", "type": "dept"}]
```

I want to add `user3` to the `group1` and written below query:

```
update t1 set names = JSON_SET(names, "$.name", JSON_ARRAY('user3')) where group = 'group1';
```

However, the above query is not working

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Show desired final data state.

Comment: Group is a reserved word in MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want the result to be:

```
[{"name": "name1", "type": "user"}, {"name": "name2", "type": "user"}, {"name": "techDept", "type": "dept"}, {"name": "user3", "type": "user"}]
```

This should work:

```
UPDATE t1 SET names = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(names, '$', JSON_OBJECT('name', 'user3', 'type', 'user'))
WHERE `group` = 'group1';
```

But it's not clear why you are using JSON at all. The normal way to store this data would be to create a second table for group members:

```
CREATE TABLE group_members (
  member_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  `group` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  member_type ENUM('user','dept') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
  name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

Then store one per row.

Adding a new member would be like:

```
INSERT INTO group_members
SET `group` = 'group1', name = 'user3';
```

So much simpler than using JSON!